# How to check a google spreadsheet before processing a form?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have tickets I'm selling for an event, and I have a google spreadsheet with a list of email addresses that should get a discount.

I'd like to check the google sheet once a user types in their email address in the form, and then if theirs is in our list, the discount gets applied.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this. The example code here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js requires users to allow access to their google drive, which isn't what I need. I just need to check my own spreadsheet.

How might I do this?

Comment: Where does the discount get applied to?

Comment: In a span that displays calculated price. It takes into account the discount and the number of tickets selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apps Script (since you're using Forms), if you want a handy solution. I don't know the complexity of your usecase but I'll just demo that this is doable:

So this is my spreadsheet, you can see the names on Column A:

```
name(0,0)
floyd(1,0)
conor(2,0)
john
carmack
borja
adam
```

I'm going to look for "adam"

```
function findPerson() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getSheets()[0].getRange("A1:A7").getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i < range.length ; i++){
     Logger.log(range[i]);

    if(   range[i] == "adam"){
      Logger.log("FOUND YAH!");
    }
  }
}
```

And there, I found him! ;)

If that's a Google Form you're using, the next step would be learning how to [Connect Spreadsheet to Google Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#connecting_to_google_forms)

Comment: I'm using an html form.